# Stripe Payment Works on LocalHost but Does not work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

Hope all is good 
I am baffled by why my stripe payment in ruby on rails works on my localhost which is c9.io account but when I deployed my code in Heroku, it gives me this error:

> Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

my orders.coffee file:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      obj = Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
      $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

out come of my orders.coffee in localhost:

[image]

my application.html.erb header section

```
<head>
  <title>Estydemo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  'https://js.stripe.com/v2/', type: 'text/javascript' %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name=> 'stripe-key', :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
</head>
```

my orders_controller.rb stripe section:

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["stripe_api_key"]
    #flash[:notice] = Stripe.api_key
    #puts "stripe api key is " + Stripe.api_key
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :source  => token,
        :description => "Customer.create"
        )
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
        :description => 'charge.create',
        :currency => "usd",
        :customer    => customer.id
        )
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
       flash[:danger] = e.message
    end
```

my application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

my stripe dashboard for a sample where I get from heroku

[image]

Could anyone let me know why I have such an odd issue?
left one is from heroku and right one is from localhost
[image]
If there is more info needed, please ask it away.

Comment: Are you mixing test and production API keys perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you rephrase your question please? What eelse would you think be an issue?

Comment: You presumably have separate Stripe API keys for your test/dev and production environments so are you using the right keys everywhere at Heroku?

Comment: @muistooshort yes I checked everything is ok

Comment: @muistooshort I added my github account to my profile If you would like to check my code. :)

Comment: I donot understand why out of the sudden I get up votes and the answers which **did not help me AT ALL** get votes too?!!!! Sounds odd and weird :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this error means that the [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) (`Stripe::Charge.create(...)`) failed because the customer has no payment source.

This in turn means that when you [created the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer):

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :source  => token,
  :description => "Customer.create"
)
```

`token` must have been either `nil` or an empty string, and as a result no `source` parameter was sent to Stripe. You can check this by looking at the log entry for the customer creation request in your Stripe dashboard.

This in turn means that `params[:stripeToken]` was itself `nil` or an empty string.

Unfortunately I'm not sure why that's the case. I'd recommend adding some logs, both in the `stripeResponseHandler` callback in your CoffeeScript file and in the Rails controller, to check whether the token was created and submitted successfully.

Comment: you were right. For some reason in heroku I do not get any value for params[:stripeToken] ? Do you think heroku have issue with coffee script?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Could you add an alert in the `stripeResponseHandler` callback after appending the hidden `stripeToken` field but before submitting the form, to make sure that `stripeToken` does contain the token?

Comment: I added my github account to my profile If you would like to check my code. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think when test on Heroku, you create charge with new customer and this customer haven't any card default active. Please add create new card before create charge on orders_controller.rb

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["stripe_api_key"]
    #flash[:notice] = Stripe.api_key
    #puts "stripe api key is " + Stripe.api_key
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :source  => token,
        :description => "Customer.create"
        )

      card = customer.sources.create({:source => token})

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
        :description => 'charge.create',
        :currency => "usd",
        :customer => customer.id,
        :source => card.id
        )
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
       flash[:danger] = e.message
    end
```

Comment: I tried yet I get this error that I cannot use source twice

Comment: do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: How to chat with you

Comment: Try to remove :source  => token when create customer

Comment: I added my github account to my profile If you would like to check my code. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think your error is simply that you're creating a Stripe customer account and passing the token to the Customer but not passing the token to the actual Charge. This needs to be done in both cases. Many use cases for Stripe can be for creating subscriptions or for processing the payment later which is why the Customer Create will take the token on file. But to create a charge you also need to do this. So I would edit the code to include the token in the Charge create like this:

**Edited 11/03**
Actually I went ahead and reverted the code back to what you had. From reading through the API some more I think that you may be able to make it work this way just fine. That is if you intend on creating a customer that can be charged again later.The direction I would look then is at the fact that it works locally but not on Heroku. I think this is less about the Stripe code and more about the change to production. Look at the ENV variable and seeing if it's set for both dev and production. But not only that, I would precompile your assets as Heroku tends to have an issue with CSS or jQuery at least for me when I go from dev to production. Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and that should do the trick, then push to master.

**See:** https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

```
token = params[:stripeToken]

begin
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :source  => token,
    :description => "Customer.create"
    )
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :description => 'charge.create',
    :currency => "usd",
    :customer    => customer.id
    )
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:danger] = e.message
end
```

If you're just looking to charge them but not retain the information in Stripe you can just use:

```
token = params[:stripeToken]

begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :currency => "usd",
    :source => token,
    :description => "Example charge"
  )
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:danger] = e.message
end
```

**Edit 11/07**
Ok so in looking through the actual repo, I think that you are having an issue because you don't have the necessary javascript call to create the token in the first place. I would reference the Stripe Api here: 
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-card-details
and insert this into your orders.js file, but that's contingent on the various input fields being named with those classes in the form you use to create the order. I hope this now helps point you in the correct direction. Everything else is looking like it should be good from what I can tell.

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: $('.card-number').val(),
  cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
  exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
  exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
}, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Comment: when I flash[:alert] the value of token , I do not get anything.  unless token = params[:stripeToken]
      flash[:alert] = 'You did not submit the form correctly'
    end  always  I get you did not submit the form correctly alert

Comment: I did what you said and I get this error Customer cus_x  does not have a linked source with ID tok_y.

Comment: sorry for my late response. fist I had this issue,Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). I put gem 'pg' in global and no error, yet I am not sure. I ran the assets piple line as you suggested and yet I still have the issue. I am willing to share my github if you want to in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: I added my github account to my profile If you would like to check my code. :)

Comment: Take a look at your orders form. I see that you have nil repeatedly listed there and from what I can tell that may be part of the issue as it's not getting the data entered in the form and passing it nil instead. Specifically look at card number, card code, select_month and select_year.  You have nil listed on the text fields. It looks like it's a form error.

Comment: I got rid of all the nils in my order form and still same issue

Comment: In looking back at the repo I see you do have it written in coffeescript but I would change what you have to be explicit. Try changing what you have which selects the entire form and try to pass each section of the form specifically to the Stripe.card.createToken action as specified by my last edit. Give each section a class that matches what I've posted above and try that as an option.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it would work on localhost and not on Heroku. That's why I thought it was an error with the asset pipeline for Heroku but in looking at the error more closely and reading up on the API I'm beginning to think that it's more related to the JS and the fact that it is failing in the creation of a Stripe Token which is why the Customer create fails. There's no issue with the Stripe Key because it's obviously communicating with Stripe but there is an issue after that. That leads me to believe that the JS isn't getting called appropriately, which is common w/ Heroku assets

Comment: So this could be an issue related to the form submission or possibly the JS/coffeescript getting called to create the Token which is then used to create the customer and charge from that point.